# npm install killed without a good error

Tags: angular, npm, vps, npm-install, angular-cli

When I run

```
ng new new-app
```

to create an angular2 app, angular-cli creates the files and runs

```
npm install
```

**The npm install is then killed without any error message.** Almost all answers online pointed to a possible problem with running out of memory, so I upgraded my VPS from 512MB to 1GB of RAM.

It seems unlikely to me that a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 with 1GB RAM cannot npm install a standard angular2 app. **Is there anything else I can try other than adding swap or ram?**

Thanks!

Comment: Try settings your npm log level to info by running `npm config set loglevel info`

Comment: the logs, even on verbose level, don't display any error. The process just gets killed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adding RAM to the machine solved the problem** (from 1GB to 2GB).

If someone else encounters the problem and cannot or doesn't want to add RAM, **consider using yarn instead of npm**.