# When to use Yarn over NPM? What are the differences?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

What are the differences between [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) and NPM?
At the time of writing this question I can only find some articles on the Internet showing [what's the Yarn equivalent of an NPM command](https://shift.infinite.red/npm-vs-yarn-cheat-sheet-8755b092e5cc#.oge4nxdqb).

Do they have the same functionalities (I know Yarn does local caching and looks like you only need to download a package once) but other than this is there any benefits for moving from NPM to Yarn?

Comment: This is not a bad question and does not deserve a downvote. That said, it does need to be fleshed out a bit to make it a truly good question.

Comment: A quick Google turns up [this](https://shift.infinite.red/npm-vs-yarn-cheat-sheet-8755b092e5cc#.5ib2khhux). I believe this is probably [too broad/not constructive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251328/can-questions-that-ask-for-a-comparison-be-constructive) for StackOverflow and could do with a bit more research shown anyway.

Comment: @Aurora0001 when I searched I saw the cheatsheet but that's not the answer to my question! I want to know differences between the two and not differences between the commands. Please read my question first

Comment: @Asha You should edit your question to have more specifics, and show what you've already researched. What kind of differences are you looking to find? Are you attempting to find out how the libraries are implemented? Are you attempting to find out how they differ in approaching the problem? If you make your question more precise, it can be good, depending on what you're asking. (Depending on what you're asking, the information may already be available on Google.)

Comment: @Asha, if you'd shown that you had read that but it wasn't relevant, it would have been helpful to show research effort. As I say though, comparison questions are usually not great for Q&A, and it might have been better if you'd framed the question differently.

Comment: Good question here.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

## UPDATE: March 2018 (bit late...)

Since version 5, `npm`

- generates a 'lockfile' called `package-lock.json` that fixes your entire dependency tree much the same way the yarn (or any other) locking mechanism does,
- A tool has been made
- `--save` is now implied for `npm i`
- Better network and cache usage

[npm 5.7.0 further introduced](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/171139955345/v570) the `npm ci` command to install dependencies more quickly in a continuous integration environment by only installing packages found in the `package-lock.json` (reporting an error if the `package-lock.json` and `package.json` are not synchronized).

*Personally*, I still use `npm`.

---

## Original

I am loathe to quote directly from docs, but they do a *great* job of explaining why, concisely enough that I don't see how to further summarize the ideas.

Largely:

1. You always know you're getting the same thing on every development
   machine
2. It paralellizes operations that `npm` does not, and
3. It makes more efficient use of the network.
4. It may make more efficient [use of other system resources (such as RAM)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987433/114900) as well.

What are people's production experiences with it? Who knows, it's an infant to the general public.

## TL;DR [from Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2016/10/11/im-excited-to-work-on-yarn-the-new-js-package-manager-2/):

> From the get-go, the Yarn lockfile guarantees that repeatedly running
>   yarn on the same repository results in the same packages.
>
> Second, Yarn attempts to have good performance, with a cold cache, but
>   especially with a warm cache.
>
> Finally, Yarn makes security a core value.

### Nice blog post

“[NPM vs Yarn Cheat Sheet](https://shift.infinite.red/npm-vs-yarn-cheat-sheet-8755b092e5cc)” by Gant Laborde

### Slightly longer version [from the project](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/README.md):

> Fast: Yarn caches every package it downloads so it never needs to
>   again. It also parallelizes operations to maximize resource
>   utilization so install times are faster than ever.
>
> Reliable: Using a detailed, but concise, lockfile format, and a
>   deterministic algorithm for installs, Yarn is able to guarantee that
>   an install that worked on one system will work exactly the same way on
>   any other system.
>
> Secure: Yarn uses checksums to verify the integrity of every installed
>   package before its code is executed.

### And from [the README.md](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/README.md):

> - Offline Mode: If you've installed a package before, you can install it again without any internet connection.
> - Deterministic: The same dependencies will be installed the same exact way across every machine regardless of install order.
> - Network Performance: Yarn efficiently queues up requests and avoids request waterfalls in order to maximize network utilization.
> - Multiple Registries: Install any package from either npm or Bower and keep your package workflow the same.
> - Network Resilience: A single request failing won't cause an install to fail. Requests are retried upon failure.
> - Flat Mode: Resolve mismatching versions of dependencies to a single version to avoid creating duplicates.
> - More emojis.

Comment: Can you tell me if yarn does dependency resolution [like npm v3 does](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3)? I understand that there is a `--flat` option which forces a *real* flat structure where only one version of each dependency is allowed to be installed, but what is the default behaviour on this? Thanks.

Comment: Excellent answer. I wonder if they tried contributing to npm before forking and renaming and changing the syntax of `install -g`.

Comment: very good post  https://scotch.io/tutorials/yarn-package-manager-an-improvement-over-npm

Answer (score 10):

Trying to give a better overview for beginners.

**npm** has been historically (2010) the most popular package manager for JavaScript. If you want to use it for managing the dependencies of your project, you can type the following command:

```
npm init
```

This will generate a `package.json` file. It contains all the dependencies of the project.

Then

```
npm install
```

would create a directory `node_modules` and download the dependencies (that you added to the `package.json` file) inside it.

It will also create a `package-lock.json` file. This file is used to describe the tree of dependecies that was generated. It allows developpers to install exectly the same dependencies. For example, you could imagine a developper upgrading a dependency to v2 and then v3 while another one directly upgrading to v3.

**npm** installs dependencies in a non-deterministically way meaning the two developper could have a different `node_modules` directory resulting into **different behaviours**.  **npm has suffered from bad reputation as for example
in February 2018: an issue was discovered in version 5.7.0 in which running sudo npm on Linux systems would change the ownership of system files, permanently breaking the operating system.

To resolve those problems and others, [Facebook introduced a new package manager](https://code.fb.com/web/yarn-a-new-package-manager-for-javascript/) (2016): **Yarn** a **faster, more securely, and more reliably** package manager for JavaScript.

You can add **Yarn** to a project by typing:

`yarn init`

This will create a `package.json` file. Then, install the dependencies with:

`yarn install`

A folder `node_modules` will be generated. **Yarn** will also generate a file called `yarn.lock`. This file serve the same purpose as the `package-lock.json` but is instead constructed using a deterministic and reliable algorithm thus leading to consistant builds.

If you started a project with **npm**, you can actually migrate to **Yarn** easily. yarn will consume the same `package.json`. See [Migrating from npm](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/) for more details.

However, **npm** has been improved with each new releases and some projects still uses **npm** over **yarn**.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @msanford covers almost everything, however, I'm missing the security (OWASP's Known Vulnerabilities) part.

**Yarn**

You can check them using `yarn audit`, however, you cannot fix them. This is still an open issue on a GitHub (https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7075).

**npm**

You can use `npm audit fix`, so some of them you can fix by yourself.

Both of them, i.e. `npm audit` & `yarn audit` have their own Continuous Integration tools. These are respectively https://github.com/IBM/audit-ci (used, works great!) and https://yarnpkg.com/package/audit-ci (haven't used).

Answer (score 5):

**npm**:

1. The package manager for JavaScript. npm is the command-line
   interface to the npm ecosystem. It is battle-tested, surprisingly
   flexible, and used by hundreds of thousands of JavaScript developers
   every day.
2. NPM generates a correct lock file whereas a Yarn lock file could be
   corrupt in some cases and has to be fixed with yarn-tools

**Yarn**:

1. A new package manager for JavaScript. Yarn caches every package it
   downloads so it never needs to again. It also parallelizes
   operations to maximize resource utilization so install times are
   faster than ever.
2. Yarn doesn't support login with a password (while NPM does)

Comment: what kind of logins?

Answer (score 3):

When you install a package using Yarn (using yarn add packagename), it **places the package on your disk**. During the next install, this package will be used instead of sending an HTTP request to get the tarball from the registry.

Yarn comes with a **handy license checker**, which can become really powerful in case you have to check the licenses of all the modules you depend on.

If you are working on proprietary software, it does not really matter which one you use. With npm, you can use npm-shrinkwrap.js, while you can use yarn.lock with Yarn.

For more information please read the following blog

https://blog.risingstack.com/yarn-vs-npm-node-js-package-managers/

Answer (score 1):

> Yarn

**Advantages::**

- Supports features like parallel installation and
  Zero-Install results in better performance
- More secure
- Large active user community

**Disadvantages::**

- Doesn’t work with older versions of Node.js (lower than version 5)
- Problems with installing native modules

> NPM

**Advantages::**

- Ease of use, especially for developers working with older
  versions.
- Optimized local package installation to save hard drive space.

**Disadvantages::**

- Security vulnerabilities are still there

***Conclusion:***

> ***Is Yarn better than NPM?***

In terms of speed and performance Yarn is better than NPM because it performs the parallel installation. Yarn is still more secure than NPM. However, Yarn uses more disk space than NPM.

Answer (score 0):

**Yarn since version 4** includes a command [`yarn upgrade-interactive`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/upgrade-interactive). Previously it had to be installed manually, but now this core plugin is built-in. It has a great CLI interface enabling you to pick the update version, possibly upgrading to new major version of your dependency. In npm, there is no such command. Closest **NPM equivalent** is [3rd party package `npm-check-updates`](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates) which has to be installed manually.

**NPM has** `npm link` command *which actually works*. It enables you to 'install' local package - usually a library - to be tested in other local project where you use it. This command is known to be [problematic or non-working in yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1297).

Other advantage of yarn was great tooling for workspace management, making it even comparable to lerna, but since version 8, even the npm has usable workspace utilities.