# Axios version package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I would like to switch to axios 0.12 version . It's posible to go back from the latest version?

```
"axios": {
      "version": "0.16.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.16.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-uk+S8XFn37q0CYN4VFS5rBScPG0=",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "1.2.4",
        "is-buffer": "1.1.5"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The generic form is as follows:

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

For example: npm install foobar@2.0.0

You can also add the `--save` flag to that command to add it to your `package.json` dependencies, or `--save --save-exact` flags if you want that exact version specified in your package.json dependencies.

If you're not sure what versions of a package are available, you can use:

```
npm view <package> versions
```

I will recommend you to go through [documentation of the npm install command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Although completely unrelated to this question, I would recommend you to read about [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) and [yarn on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027819/when-to-use-yarn-over-npm-what-are-the-differences)