# Can we use npm package using symfony Encore

Tags: symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

Hi I was wondering if we could use npm packages in the Symfony replacements...  And if it's possible you can tell me how please

Answer (score 0):

You can create all of frontend things in your `public` folder (for explain (`/public/frontend/`), init the `npm`, `Webpack` (if you want), and require generated CSS and JS files, in your `base.html.twig` template.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the documentation [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html).

You can use `npm` or `yarn` which is similar but a still little bit different [When to use Yarn over NPM? What are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027819/when-to-use-yarn-over-npm-what-are-the-differences/40028313)